# How to implement a TabViewBarController Programmatically after (not as primary view) login page

Tags: ios, swift

Hello I was wondering if there is a way or how to make a tabBarControllerView once the user logs in programmatically without using storyboard. After doing research I found out how to do it by setting in the appDelegate the tabBarViewcontroller class as rootview. But my root view is the login screen. I was wondering if there was a way to do create a tabBarView and load it once the app reaches a certain ViewController/screen.
Here is my tabBarViewController class so far:

```swift
import Foundation
import UIKit

class tabBarControllerView: UITabBarController{
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        UINavigationBar.appearance().prefersLargeTitles = true
        viewControllers = 
        [UserProfileControllerUIKIT(),MainPageUIKIT(),OtherPageUIKit()]
    }
}
```

Here is my appDelegate:
//

```swift
import UIKit
import Firebase

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {
    var window: UIWindow?
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: 
         [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        FirebaseApp.configure()
        window = UIWindow()
        window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
        window?.rootViewController = tabBarControllerView()
        return true
    }

    // MARK: UISceneSession Lifecycle

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, configurationForConnecting connectingSceneSession: UISceneSession, options: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) -> UISceneConfiguration {
        // Called when a new scene session is being created.
        // Use this method to select a configuration to create the new scene with.
        return UISceneConfiguration(name: "Default Configuration", sessionRole: connectingSceneSession.role)
    }

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didDiscardSceneSessions sceneSessions: Set<UISceneSession>) {
        // Called when the user discards a scene session.
        // If any sessions were discarded while the application was not running, this will be called shortly after application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions.
        // Use this method to release any resources that were specific to the discarded scenes, as they will not return.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change rootviewcontroller after login

```
let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
appDelegate.window?.rootViewController = tabBarControllerView()
appDelegate.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

Comment: In what class would I put that code in? (Sorry I'm new to this)

Comment: in your case, I think it will be in LoginViewController when user success login